# how to set thread-safe global variable in Kotlin companion object?

Tags: kotlin, global-variables

I want to set a mutable variable in companion object and use it in other methods in static way.

```
class GlobalVariable {
    companion object {
        private var flag = false

        fun modifyFlag(){
          flag = setFlagValue() //this method written in other class to assign value to the flag
        }
        fun getVal(): Boolean = this.flag // this is to get flag value in other methods static way, like GlobalVariable.getVal()
    }
}
```

the `flag` is the variable I need, I'll call `modifyFlag()` method in other methods, set value to the flag, then use `GlobalVariable.getVal()` in whenever I need.

not sure whether it's thread-safe in this way. 
Is there any other way to set a global variable in Kotlin?

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if it helped you or if you are looking for another solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this if you run your Kotlin app on JVM. The annotation `@Synchronized` will lock the methods, so the threads will not access the static class while the method is executed.

```
class GlobalVariable {
    companion object {
        private var mutex = Object()
        private var flag = false

        @Synchronized fun modifyFlag(){
            flag = setFlagValue()
        }

        @Synchronized fun getVal(): Boolean = this.flag
    }
}
```

You can also use synchronized block, however, due to official documentation, synchronization on Any object is not supported on every platform and will be removed soon from standard library.

```
class GlobalVariable {
    companion object {
        private var mutex = Object()
        private var flag = false

        private val mutex = Any()

        fun modifyFlag(){
            synchronized(mutex) {
                flag = setFlagValue()
            }
        }

        fun getVal(): Boolean {
            synchronized(mutex) {
                return flag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, synchronized block allows only one thread to obtain mutex at time. The thread, which will hold the mutex, will execute the method, not being interrupted or involved to race by other threads

Comment: thanks for your help,  I tried the annotation way, when the first time set the flag to true, the second call enter, found the flag was not reset to false in the method `modifyFlag()`.

Comment: @wai4y can you please post implementation of `setFlagValue()`?

Comment: the `setFlagValue()` returns a boolean, the first time I made it return true, the flag value was set to true, then the second request, when I debug to the line `flag = setFlagValue()`, before the flag was assigned a value, it's already with the value true

Comment: @wai4y are you sure, that `setFlagValue()` return not only true? According to your explanation, it does not return false, therefore flag will not be reset to false after second call of `modifyFlag()`

Comment: the logic can change on front-end, so the `setFlagValue()` can return true or false, what I'm curious is that after the first time I set it to true, the second request when debug hit this line, the flag didn't reset to its default vaule which is false I defined above the `modifyFlag()` method.